# how do I assign a value to a word for easy use when referencing the value of said word?

Tags: c

I am currently trying to make a small game in the c programing language for a portfolio. I am new to c so I don't know all of the ticks. Currently, I am trying to assign values to enum's though I don't know if that is correct.

```
// C program for generating a
// random number in a given range.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Test.h"

enum mods{
Cha, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis      // <-this line is the only line that is my code (of this document I have more that will reference this document) the rest I learned from others 
};




// Generates and prints 'count' random
// numbers in range [lower, upper].
void printRandoms(int lower, int upper,
                             int count)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int num = (rand() %
           (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
}

// Driver code
int main(enum mods Str)
{
    int lower = 6, upper = 18, count = 1;

    // Use current time as
    // seed for random generator
    srand(time(0));

    printRandoms(lower, upper, count);


    printf("My enum Value : %d\n", (int)Str); 

    return 0;
```

*edit Sorry for the confusion. I want to be able to reference this product of this line of code over and over again in the main sheet/program. I want it to be a random start so it isn't the same game every time. How do I do that? (for an example of the end product:

```
if (Str >= 10) 
 printf("pass skill check to lift the log\n");

else
 printf("you drop the log on your foot and take 1d4 damage\n");
enum (health -1d4[will make actual code for this but not yet])
```

what I need answered

how to make each of the enum mods = a random number at the start of the program to be referenced in the main program

)

Comment: `int main(enum mods Str)` That's not a valid `main`. C requires main to be `int main(void)` or `int man(int argc, char **argv)`. That's just one issue but it's unclear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the mod values to be randomly generated.
Use the enum values as array indices into an array big enough to hold all your mod attributes. Like this, for example:

```
enum mods = { Cha, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Mod_Max };
int mod_values[Mod_Max];
```

Keeping `Mod_Max` (or whatever you'd like to call it) as the last element of the enum, this will give you  simple way to refer to the size of the array. Populating the array with values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Mod_Max; i++) {
    mod_values[i] = ...;
}
```

And getting a value of a given "mod" would simply be (for example Str):

`mod_values[Str];`

EDIT: This way, lets you further modify the mod values down the line, rather than having them as constants

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thank you! I am sorry for the confusing question I guess I didn't make my question clear again. Sorry about that to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to have values for each element in your `enum`. Well all you have to do is simply assign said value-

```c
enum mods { foo = 77, bar = 42, baz = 3 };
```

Then you can access said values like so-

```c
enum mods mod_enum = foo;
printf("%d", mod_enum);
```

The above will print `77`

You can also directly use the value of one of the elements from said `enum`

```c
printf("%d\n", bar);
```

The above prints `42`

Read more about [`enum`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum)

Comment: Thank you for answering, and the link. This will be very helpful. However, this isn't quite what I need. but it was helpful, Thank You!